# Buttons in master page ASP.NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every time I try to add a button to my master page, I got this error :
    Control 'Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

P.S : the button is inside a div tag with runat=server !

Comment: The error says `<form runat="server"></form>`

Comment: your button should be inside form tag.

Comment: but I don't want to put my button inside a form. It's a button with an action attached to .cs file. No forms !

Comment: @Fady, only John Skeet can put button onto a aspx page outside a server form

Answer (score 2):

It's inside a `div` tag. It must be inside a `form` tag, like this:

```
<form runat="server">
 // button here
</form>
```

Comment: but I don't want to put my button inside a form. It's a button with an action attached to .cs file. No forms !

Comment: Sorry - buttons have to be inside of forms, that's all there is to it. That's the way they work!

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually mean that the user has to fill out a form - it's just a `form` HTML element that the button must reside in.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the body tag, you have a form tag like this

```
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
```

All server controls must appear within a `<form>` tag, and the `<form>` tag must contain the runat="server" attribute.

[For more information about the form tag..Check this page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Now is it okay to you (if you want to keep your `Div`)

```
<form Id="MyForm" runat="server">
      <div Id="MyDiv" runat="server">
         // Here your HTML.
      </div>
</form>
```

This is because in ASP.NET one page should have one `Form` with `runat = "server"` tag and in Master page we keep this `Form` tag and in content page we keep other required controls.